# glib produces lots of errors on fresh 11.10 install

Tags: 11.10, unity, cpu, glib

I have just freshly installed 11.10 64bit on my 3Ghz dual core machine with graphic card nvidia 9600gt and 290.10 driver.

The desktop crashes or will be not redraw correctly. It's very unstable when using Skype or log file viewer and other applications. I get massive error outputs in xsession-error log related to gdk or glib.

I was previously using Ubuntu 10.04 64bit for a long time without any problems; I was also using the same graphic driver without any problems and compiz was running successfully.

This is an example of the error output from just a few minutes using desktop after reboot:[xsession-errors log](http://www.pasteall.org/28512)
Is it possible to fix it?

Also CPU usage is so much higher than before. What if I want to start 3d rendering or use my other CPU intensive applications? How should I configure it? Now I have just Skype and Google Chrome and log viewer running and the CPU usage is at 50%.

---

Update: I did another fresh installation. This time I didn't take the newest nvidia driver, but the one from the repository 280.13. CPU values seams to be normal now, but I still received xsession-errors:[link](http://www.pasteall.org/28550).

My system is 2 minutes old (up-to-date), no ppa in the packadge management. Absolutly clean. I am running just Firefox + log viewer. For the record, this was the 7th installation of this system. Why am I not able to install and get it to a normal state?

My graphic card is supported. I was running this card on the newest driver already and made fantastic 3d renderings on it. What else can I do? Take another distro? Is it possible to fix this problem? I don't want to give up ubuntu. It has been my favorite operating for a long time.

My graphic driver is not loaded:[enter link description here](http://www.pasteall.org/28512) Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem this way:

- I made a fresh install of Ubuntu
- after the system update, I did not install a proprietary graphic driver from the repos, I left just the one which is open source: 173.* -- which Ubuntu installs automatically.
- I enabled proposed (pre-released) updates in synaptic and added this ppa to the repository: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu
- then I executed `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
- `reboot`

The problem with other instructions was that the newest kernel 3.0.0.16 didn't work with the 280.10 nvidia driver on my computer and I got a mismatched API or the machine didn't boot or I had a massive list of errors in xsession-erros log and CPU disaster.

The glib errors still appear in the logs, but not as much as before. The computer runs wonderfully, very fast and stable now. Some of the errors will be gone after installation of some packets and a little bit of tuning here and there. The rest is just not important I guess.

(Something must be done to kernel updates + Nvidia updates)

Answer (score 1):

Check your software sources to see if you have proposed enabled if not enable it.

Then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login,
and do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

When it's finished do `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current*`
then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

I had this happen to me on a new install and it worked for me!

If this doesn't help add the **ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa** and do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: great, this was a nice tip. Thank you very much. My driver is now loaded! But the glib errors are not gone [link](http://www.pasteall.org/28570) Also recovery mode menu is not drawing in the right way...so is hard for me to choose right menu point.

Comment: just out of curiosity when you did the update and dist-upgrade did the update install a new kernel? if it did you may have to repeat the process with that kernel: is dkms installed? or perhaps download a fresh iso of ubuntu perhaps the one you used was corrupt! like denNorske wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run this from tty: (press CTRL + ALT + F1 or F2 or F3)

> Compiz --replace

(if it is Compiz u have as default screen manager?)

> unity --replace

(if it is unity as default)

cause it can maybe be the problem..

Comment: i am using unity, isnt compiz based?

Comment: so i made unity --replace from tty. I ve got a lot of errors. Some of them here: glib.glib -  gobject <unknown>: = invalis (NULL) pointer instance; compiz(shift)- no compatible text plugin loaded; unity-panel-service: no prcess found; compiz(unity)-Warn: unsupported internal format, segmentation fault. I could just reboot after that. Now is just web browser open - CPU usage 60%

Comment: pls look at the xseassion-erross log after reboot: http://www.pasteall.org/28514

Comment: also i discover some strange thing. the comsole putpu of inxi about my system discover that my new driver is not loaded:Graphics:  Card: nVidia G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] 
           X.Org 1.10.4 drivers nvidia unloaded: nouveau,vesa,fbdev Resolution 1920x1080@50.0hz 
but in nvidia setting control i see that driver. What about?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Grub at the boot stage, navigate down to recovery-mode, and try to fix it from there . I will strongly reccommend you to do a fresh, new install. Once more :S the install looks corrupt to me. Are you sure the graphics card s supported? do a research :)

Comment: my graphiccard is DEFINITLY supported. but something is wrong with loading of the driver: "Graphics: Card: nVidia G94 [GeForce 9600 GT] X.Org 1.10.4 drivers nvidia unloaded: nouveau,vesa,fbdev Resolution 1920x1080@50.0hz" and in the nvidia control settings the driver 290.10 is enabled.